# Is this matrices exist, with this propertie

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

if $\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    1
   \end{bmatrix}$ $\in R(A)$, and $\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    5
   \end{bmatrix}$,
 $\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2
   \end{bmatrix}$ $\in R(A^{T})$

I think that is not exist because, from here we can see that this matrices must be $3x2$ but when I find base of $N(A)$ and $N(A^{T})$ they have dimension 1, so than we need matrice $3x3$ which is not what we expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and note that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$ therefore $R(A^T)$ = $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: But from this matrices you can not get the same base for $R(A^{T})$ as I write

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić The condition you gave is that $\in R(A)$, and $\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    5
   \end{bmatrix}$,
 $\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2
   \end{bmatrix}$ $\in R(A^{T})$ and of course that condition is fulfilled by A.

Comment: Yes but do you know how to get base of fundamental subspace when you have some matrices?

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić Yes of course a basis for $R(A)$ is $(1,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and for $R(A^T)$ is $(1,0), (0,1)$ or $(2,5), (1,2)$.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I hate this when I watch this and do not see that is true, thank you!

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić You are welcome! Bye